# getColumnMeta does not return correct field type

Tags: php, pdo

I have innodb table with the following scheme, running MySQL 5.5:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
```

I am trying to use [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) to get `id` column type, but it gives wrong data:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["native_type"]=>
    string(4) "LONG"
    ["flags"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "not_null"
      [1]=>
      string(11) "primary_key"
    }
    ["table"]=>
    string(7) "entries"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["len"]=>
    int(10)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["pdo_type"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["native_type"]=>
    string(4) "LONG"
    ["flags"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "multiple_key"
    }
    ["table"]=>
    string(7) "entries"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "category_id"
    ["len"]=>
    int(10)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["pdo_type"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["native_type"]=>
    string(10) "VAR_STRING"
    ["flags"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "not_null"
    }
    ["table"]=>
    string(7) "entries"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "uuid"
    ["len"]=>
    int(108)
    ["precision"]=>
    int(0)
    ["pdo_type"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

PHP code as requested:

```
$select = $db
    ->query("
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `category_id`,
        `uuid`
    FROM
        `entries`
    LIMIT 1;
    ;
    ");


$meta   = [];

for($i = 0, $j = $select->columnCount(); $i < $j; $i++)
{
    $meta[] = $select->getColumnMeta($i);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your php code?

Comment: I must be missing something.  What is wrong?

Comment: You aren't hoping for unsigned to make it's way into the PHP types are you?

Comment: Well, how do I tell given that information that column is `INT`?

Comment: LONG is the same as INT.

Comment: @Narf Where do I learn that from?

Comment: @Guy Apart from me just saying it now - probably in any decent article about data types. :) An example is that PHP's `is_long()` function is an alias for `is_int()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this function for determining the type of a column. The documentation states that it's experimental, and the gymnastics just aren't worth it. I would use:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM [table]
```

Which will give you the pure MySQL types in the result. It's a little less elegant. but a lot more reliable.